# How to prevent VS2008 from saving bookmarks?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, editor, text-editor, bookmarks

VS2008 automatically saves bookmarks and restores them when I reopen the document. How can I tell it to stop saving them. When I open a doc, I want it without any bookmark, as in previous versions of VS.

I went twice through the whole options set but couldn't find anything related to bookmarks.

TIA.

Comment: I have never heard of bookmark before, forgive my ignorance. if you tell it more detailed, i might help you. ? Did you mention Auto-recover or something like that ?

Comment: Well, if you've never heard of them before, I doubt you could help ;-) Want to know more? Play with the Edit/Bookmarks submenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write a macro that handles the `DocumentEvents` or `WindowEvents` event interfaces.

In response to (e.g.) `DocumentEvents_OnDocumentOpened`, which gets a `Document` object, you should be able to remove all of the bookmarks.

Or, if bookmarks are relative to a window, you might need to handle `WindowEvents_OnWindowCreated`.

The documentation claims that these are for Microsoft internal use only, but it says the same for `BuildEvents`, and I've been using those successfully since VS2003.

Answer (score 2):

The CTRL+B CTRL+C key combo clears all the bookmarks.  You could use that before saving although it wipes out all the bookmarks in all files and displays a confirm dialog.